# Mass Effect 1 wont start

Tags: pc, technical-issues, mass-effect

Just bought Mass Effect 1 from Origin on my new rig.

Every time I try to start it, just stops working. I can't even get to the title screen. Running the game with Admin privileges doesn't help. All of my drivers are up to date.

When I start the game, it takes me to the configuration utility.  When I press play in the utility it goes to the ME logo, then my screen goes black for 2 seconds and a message pops up saying ME.exe stopped working.

My specs are:

- Windows 7 Ultimate
- AMD Phenom processor
- Sapphire Radeon HD 6850
- 8 gigs of ram

Comment: You can edit questions if you need to add more information, there's no need to delete and repost :)

Comment: What's in the details of the error message? Could you add a PasteBin link with those details?

Comment: Are you using Steam or Origin version?

Comment: Origin, and it just says ME.exe stopped working and thats it

Comment: Any sort of crash logs in the game directory?  You could look in the application events in the event viewer. See if there is an error for the game there.

Comment: What happens if you set compatibility for an older version of Windows on the Mass Effect executable and/or launch the game executable directly without the launcher? (located at `Binaries\MassEffect.exe` in your ME install folder)

Comment: Also just a heads up the config utilities from origin are known to break games, for example just opening the config util breaks me:2 and requires a fresh install, you may have to re-install and start the game without the config util.

Answer (score 2):

I had that problem in Win7 too. You can either check *Windows XP compatibility mode* in the shortcut or .exe file properties, or right-click the game shortcut and select *"Run as administrator"*